# How i can validate token in asp.net sent in header with ajax request?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: "/api/Values/endpoint",
                    data: data,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    headers: { "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + window.sessionStorage.getItem("token") },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response != null) {
                            //my code here
                        } else {
                            alert("Something went wrong");
                        }
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("fail");
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert("error");
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

I am able to send the request to the controller but not function.

this is the response I am receiving.

```
 "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
```

this is my controller function

```
    [HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Authorize]
    [Route("endpoint")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> endpoint()
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
headers: { "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + window.sessionStorage.getItem("token") },
```

try:

```
beforeSend: function (request) {
       var token =window.sessionStorage.getItem("token");
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
                    "Bearer " + token);
            },
```

Comment: this one beforeSend he should add it in each ajax request right ?

Comment: I am still getting the same Error.  I believe I am something wrong with Startup.cs file.

Comment: Post  APIs startup to check